# Change Firebase password in Ionic without Authenticating

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I want to change a user's password without authenticating the user, and I want to do this with Ionic.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, 
    this._password);
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials)
```

The problem is that I want to change the user's password without authenticating the user, and that's something I cannot do with firebase.auth().currentUser . The latter won't work if we are dealing with multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides only one way to reset the password without authorization i.e. [reset password by email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email).

> You can send a password reset email to a user with the
>   sendPasswordResetEmail method. For example:

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var emailAddress = "user@example.com";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

You can also customize [email template format](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the client-side JavaScript SDK to change a user's password without authenticating that user. If it existed it could be called by any malicious user of your app, which would be a pretty massive security risk.

The only way to change a user's password without knowing/specifying their current credentials is through the Firebase Admin SDK. This Admin SDK is made to be run in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions), and thus can't be abused by users of your app.